# How to loop through an array of SimpleXMLElement objects and return node default value?

Tags: php, arrays, simplexml

I am trying to get default value for each field but I just can't figure out how to loop through all the objects. Tried with converting them to a simple array with json_decode but it just not clear as to what to loop.

Here it is:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [name] => params
        )

    [fieldset] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Cat1
                        )

                    [field] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                            [@attributes] => Array
                                (
                                    [name] => 
                                    [type] => list
                                    [default] => 1
                                )
                        )
                )

            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item2
                        )

                    [field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post1
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 5
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post2
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 18
                                        )
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post3
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 15
                                        )

                                    [option] => Array
                                        (
                                            [0] => Blue
                                            [1] => Green
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )

                      [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [@attributes] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Cat2
                        )

                    [field] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post6
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 3
                                        )
                                )

                            [1] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post7
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 36
                                        )
                                )

                            [2] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                                (
                                    [@attributes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [name] => post7
                                            [type] => text
                                            [default] => 88
                                        )
                                )
                        )
                )
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this (where `$xml` is your root object)

```
foreach($xml->fieldset as $fieldset) {
    foreach($fieldset->field as $field) echo (string)$field['default'];
}
```